# Eas Update not working - branch v channel confusion?

Tags: react-native, expo, eas, expo-updates, eas-update

I read the [EAS Update docs](https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/getting-started/) and thought i understood it.  Making the updates as followed:

eas.json:

```
"production": {
      "channel": "main", 
      "env": { }
    }
```

I did not name the `channel: "production"` because I was under the impression when running `eas update --auto` it will use the name of the branch I am on.  So in this case, my "production" branch is **`"main"`**.

In my app.config:

```
updates: {
      url: 'https://u.expo.dev/hash-goes-here',
    },
    runtimeVersion: {
      policy: 'appVersion',
    },
```

In EAS, my `Channels` show:
[image]

and the `Linked Branches` shows my last update as successful:

[image]

and the `Update` shows my last update too:
[image]

I also have a useEffect to check, as suggested in the docs:

```
useEffect(function onFetchUpdateAsync() {
    async function checkIt() {
      try {
        const update = await Updates.checkForUpdateAsync();

        if (update.isAvailable) {
          await Updates.fetchUpdateAsync();
          await Updates.reloadAsync();
        }
      } catch (error) {
        // You can also add an alert() to see the error message in case of an error when fetching updates.
        console.error(`Error fetching latest Expo update: ${error}`);
        Bugsnag.notify(error as Error);
      }
    }
    if (__DEV__) return; //
    checkIt();
  }, []);
```

---

When I open my production app, I do not see the update.  I tried uninstalling & reinstalling.  I tried opening & closing multiple times.

Questions:

1. Is it true that EAS Update will auto check without a `useEffect` when the app opens & closes?
2. When running `eas update --auto`, from `main` branch, is this correctly linked to my `production` channel named `main`?
3. Is there something else I am missing on this that would not make my updates appear?